# Rotational velocity due to Dark matter

Tags: astronomy, velocity, dark-matter

I was wondering if we can predict the rotational velocity  due to dark matter in this way:

Consider that we theoretically derived the rotational velocity of a galaxy ($v_{the}$). Then from experiment we got some other rotation velocity ($v_{obs}$). Then can we subtract these two velocities to obtain the rotational velocity due to dark matter ($v_{dar}$).

If not, how can we derive $v_{dar}$ by $v_{the}$ and $v_{obs}$?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the method, though of course using the complete formulas.

Comment: You mean $v_{obs}$-$v_{the}$=$v_{dar}$ just confirming

Answer (score 1):

Radial acceleration is $v^2/r$ and this is proportional to the total mass enclosed within the orbit. Adopting a rough Keplerian approximation
$$ \frac{v^2}{r} = \frac{G}{r^2}\sum_i M_i,$$
where $M_i$ are the masses of the various components (baryonic, dark).

If I understand correctly, your "theoretical" rotation curve arises from considering only baryonic matter, whereas the observed speed corresponds to $v$ in the equation above. If so, then
$$v^2_{\rm obs}\simeq v^2_{\rm the} + v^2_{\rm dark}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks I got the concept now very clear